# Inserting an "INTO" clause to a package body

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, plsql

I have this package called `reg_user` I need to make a query that could select all the items in the table in returning it to the `java` program (using `jdbc`) so what will I need in order to return a value to be used in the java program? Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY reg_pack
AS
PROCEDURE addUser(
    c_fname user_profile.firstname%type,
    c_lname user_profile.lastname%type,
    c_cnum user_profile.contactno%type,
    c_dob USER_PROFILE.DOB%type,
    c_address user_profile.address%type,
    c_city user_profile.city%type,
    c_state user_profile.state%type,
    c_country user_profile.country%type,
    c_email user_profile.emailid%type,
    c_password user_profile.password%type,
    c_usertype user_profile.usertype%type,
    c_username user_profile.username%type)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT
  INTO USER_PROFILE
    (
      userid,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      contactno,
      dob,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      country,
      emailid,
      password,
      usertype,
      username
    )
    VALUES
    (
      userid_seq.NEXTVAL,
      c_fname,
      c_lname,
      c_cnum,
      c_dob,
      c_address,
      c_city,
      c_state,
      c_country,
      c_email,
      c_password,
      c_usertype,
      c_username
    );
END addUser;
PROCEDURE delUser
  (
    c_id user_profile.userid%type
  )
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM USER_PROFILE WHERE user_profile.userid = c_id;
END delUser;
PROCEDURE selectUser(
    c_id user_profile.userid%type)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT USERID ,
    FIRSTNAME ,
    LASTNAME ,
    CONTACTNO ,
    DOB ,
    ADDRESS ,
    CITY ,
    STATE ,
    COUNTRY ,
    EMAILID ,
    PASSWORD ,
    USERTYPE ,
    USERNAME SERID ,
    FIRSTNAME ,
    LASTNAME ,
    CONTACTNO ,
    DOB ,
    ADDRESS ,
    CITY ,
    STATE ,
    COUNTRY ,
    EMAILID ,
    PASSWORD ,
    USERTYPE ,
    USERNAME
  FROM USER_PROFILE
  WHERE user_profile.userid = c_id;
END selectUser;
END reg_pack;
```

Comment: Do you control the `reg_user` package, i.e. can you modify `selectUser` in order to get some data out of the procedure? I don't think it's possible with the current code; it's declaring no `OUT` variables.

Comment: I can modify the ``selectUser``. So I should put ``OUT`` variables then?

Comment: Why do you need the package to do the query, why not just execute the query from Java/JDBC?

Comment: Because it is a requirement for us to put it in a package.

Comment: I've resolved the problem already by creating ``OUT`` and ``IN`` variables thanks! @Mick Mnemonic